# Wireless BCM4318 not working

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers

I was just about to update, or activate (as its listed in the software) my wireless driver and the hole system crashed, i rebooted and now I dont have the driver listed anymore in my aditional drivers, i have tried many things but none came back positive, can you guys help:

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe wl
```